# HTML5 correct elements usage to achieve "label and box" style

Tags: html

What is the best solution for this kind of situation from HTML5 point of view? 
I'm having a label above the box with some text inside, as presented here:

[image]

The code looks like that now:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <p class="label"> Marka </p>
    <p class="box"> Volkswagen </p>
</div>
```

I was also thinking about wrapping `<label>` and disabled `<input>` into the `<form>`, but it doesn't seem to be correct as well. I couldn't google any answer, since I don't really know how to name my problem.

Comment: I would go with the second solution that you said, with `<form>` tag, `<label>` tag and `<input>` tag. That's what they're used for

Comment: I can see some small performance issues here, and HTML is intended to DESCRIBE the content it contains. The whole thing isn't really a form.

Comment: Your markup's fine as is. You could consider using dl/dt/dd but it's not obvious that you'll gain anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use html5 tags try the following

```
    <div><label>Marka</label></div>
    <div><input type="text" disabled> <!--Remove disabled if you want it active-->
```

Just repeat for the other.